# Getting Highs of Only Red Candles

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So I have an indicator right now that plots some of the previous week highs, here's an example of what I've got:

`previousWhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1])`

The plotting and labelling of the line

```
plot(previousWhigh, style=plot.style_line,title="Last Week's High",color=#f018c1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true,offset=k)
pwh = label.new(x=time+td, y=previousWhigh, text = "Last Week's High", xloc = xloc.bar_time, style = label.style_none, textcolor = #f018c1, size = size.normal, textalign = text.align_right)
label.delete(pwh[1])
```

How would I go about making this plot on just red candles?
And is there a more efficient way to go about adding more lines rather than doing this combo so many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request `open` and `close` prices too to figure out if it is a red candle or not. Then only plot if it is a red candle.

```
[pOpen, pClose, pHigh] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', [open[1], close[1], high[1]])
pRed = pClose < pOpen
plot(pRed ? pHigh: na, style=plot.style_line,title="Last Week's High",color=#f018c1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true,offset=k)
```

Comment: When I try this I get,  "Undeclared identifier 'k'" in the log, I tried comparing this to other plots but I can't figure out what would cause the error here.

Comment: `offset=k` is in your original code. `k` must be declared somewhere.

Comment: I realized that after I made my comment, my bad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry to be a bother but, is there any way to make it so that when a candle isn't red, it doesn't label the price of the nearest red? For example, if I had `[open[8], close[8], high[8]]`, and that candle happened to be green, and candle 7 was red, it will label the price at candle 7.